# Do this sequence of sets associated to each smooth function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ have a name?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization, commutative-algebra, terminology

Given a smooth function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, define a sequence of sets as follows:

- $\Gamma_0(f) = \{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^0) \mid f(x)=0\}$
- $\Gamma_1(f) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^1) \mid f(x)=y,f'(x)=0\}$
- $\Gamma_2(f) = \{(x,y+y'\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2) \mid (f,f')(x)=(y,y'), f''(x)=0\}$
- $\Gamma_3(f) = \{(x,y+y'\varepsilon+y''\varepsilon^2) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^3) \mid (f,f',f'')(x)=(y,y',y''), f'''(x)=0\}$

etc.

For example, the set $\Gamma_0(f)$ basically consists of the roots of $f$. The set $\Gamma_1(f)$ consists of the stationary points. The set $\Gamma_2(f)$ consists of the solutions to $f''(x)=0$, equipped with knowledge of the height of $f$ at this point, and the slope of $f$. Etc.

> **Question.** Does this sequence of sets have an accepted name?